# Unable to cast object of type System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData visual studio 2012 windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

My windows phone 7.5. application works properly but after upgrading it to windows phone 8 o.s. my visual studio can't run my application and showing it error in mainpage.xaml file at 1 line  like
I have doesn't  implemented any richtext box I have implemented coading4fun toolkit.

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData'
>   to type 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute'

I have visual studio 2012 express for windows phone 8 with update 4
how can I solve that. please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a same problem.. It is because I used `<ImageSource>`

Solution:
Change `<ImageSource>` to `<BitmapImage>`

E.g- `<ImageSource x:Key="BackgroundImage" UriSource="/Resource/Background/panoramabackground.JPG"/>`
or find the changes in xaml.

Ref: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/48aab381-22ec-4ca6-88fb-7ce3e13ea1cc/upgraded-vs2012-with-update2-and-now-my-wp8-project-fails?forum=wpdevelop][1]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I copied an already defined `<Image>` tag and pasted it on the same page.

So, the previous `<Image>` tag was

```
<Image x:Name="imgWallpaperThumbnail"  Height="233"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,10,0,0" Tap="imgWallpaperThumbnail_Tap">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"  ></BitmapImage>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
```

and when I copied it and pasted it on the same page, then it gets converted to:

```
 <Image x:Name="imgWallpaperThumbnail_Copy"  Height="65" Margin="10,10,395,0" Tap="imgWallpaperThumbnail_Tap">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <ImageSource>/Assets/Ellipse.png</ImageSource>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
```

Now, check the image source, it should be `<BitmapImage>` rather than `<Image.Source>`

I would advise you to download Visual Studio Community 2015, Update 3, which provides detailed Exception.

`<Image>` is a System Control and Source is one of its property, that sets the image. But, when you applied image operations then you should use BitmapImage as it is from System.Windows.Media.Imaging that provides the object source type rather than the `<Image>` Control which is a member System.Windows.Media.